# modal popup just after login

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, custom-component, plugin-events

I am new to the Joomla world and I have to face a difficult problem.
I have to make sure that immediately after logging in to the user, a modal popup with a select box is proposed.
The content of the select must be dynamically generated after the query of an external web services.
At the end of the selection, the value chosen by the user must be entered in session.
I thought about creating a user plugin by raising the onUserAfterLogin event.
Unfortunately, I have discovered that here it is not possible to add javascript to the page.
Could you recommend me the best approach to solve this problem?

Comment: Welocome to JSE.  Please take our [tour] while you wait for the community to offer feedback/support.

Comment: What have you written so far? `onUserAfterLogin` is triggered before user is redirected to first page after login. So it may not be suitable for your case.